# how to add x axis labels ggplot2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis-labels

I would like to put some labels on ggplot bar plot X-axis.

data:

```
var.A <- as.numeric(c(1:13))
var.B <- c(4.351833, 2.938000, 4.726465, 3.747162, 3.720737, 4.297117, 4.304500, 4.061277, 4.595236, 4.105444, 3.701684, 3.523563, 4.170000)
df <- data.frame(var.A,var.B)
```

ggplot code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=var.A, y=var.B)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", fill="#fff68f", colour="darkgrey", width = 0.4) +
  coord_flip()+
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("aaaaaaa aaaaa","bbbbb bbb bbbb","cccc ccc","dddd dd ddddd","eee e eeeee e ee","ffffffff","gggggggg","hhhhhhh","iiii","jjjjjj","kkkkkkk","llllll","mmmmmmmm"))
```

I refer to docs: [ggplot documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_discrete.html)

How to force R to put this labels on their places on x-axxis?

Comment: try with `..aes(x=as.factor(var.A)..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify x as a factor. That's it.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(var.A), y=var.B)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", fill="#fff68f", colour="darkgrey", width = 0.4) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("aaaaaaa aaaaa","bbbbb bbb bbbb","cccc ccc","dddd dd ddddd","eee e eeeee e ee","ffffffff","gggggggg","hhhhhhh","iiii","jjjjjj","kkkkkkk","llllll","mmmmmmmm"))
```